# problem when using multiple AurahandledException

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I'm trying to use multiple AurahandledExceptions in the apex controller to show correct message based on where the error occurred.

Controller:

```
public static void updateRecord(String recordId, String fieldValue){
   try{
       if(String fieldValue == null){
          throw new AurahandledException('No field value specified');
       }else{
          //update Record here
       }
   } catch(Exception e){
         throw new AurahandledException('Error occurred while updating record');
   }
}
```

Now, if I pass fieldValue parameter as null, it still throws the error message : **Error occurred while updating record**.

I'm not able to understand why **No field value specified** is not displayed even though it enters the enclosing if.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The catch catches the initial error, and then you throw a second one. You might consider changing your logic:

```
public static void updateRecord(String recordId, String fieldValue){
    try{
        if(String fieldValue == null){
            throw new AurahandledException('No field value specified');
        }else{
            //update Record here
        }
    } 
    catch(AurahandledException e) {
        throw e;
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        throw new AurahandledException('An error occurred: '+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

With this design, if you specifically throw an exception, it will be passed through to the client, otherwise you'll send the other message.

Note that catch blocks are evaluated in order, so the generic exception must come after all specific exceptions in order for this design to work.